# Vim: go to line and enter insert mode

Tags: vim

How do you go to a line beginning or end and enter insert mode in vim?

For example you can delete a line number 33 with `:33d`. Is there an equivalent that lets you perform the same action as `36G` followed by `i` or `36G`, `A` so that you can go to line 36 and insert at the start of the line or the end of the line with a single command?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be an easier/shorter answer than typing `:33` hitting enter and pressing `i` or `A`.

Comment: I disagree, Stun, @romainl’s way I find easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:help :startinsert` for that:

```
:33|star     " go to line 33 and start insert mode before the cursor (like i)
:33|star!    " go to line 33 and start insert mode after the end of the line (like A)
```

Note that `:startinsert` doesn't accept a range so we must use `:help :|` as a workaround.

Also, `:startinsert` does `i` and `A` but it doesn't do `I` or `a`. I don't know of any easy workaround. If you feel adventurous, `:help feedkeys()` could help you craft your own custom commands:

```
:33|call feedkeys('I')
```

Comment: `:normal 33GI` ?

Comment: @phd That doesn't work as `:normal` can't end in Insert mode, see `:help :normal` which says "{commands} should be a complete command. If {commands} does not finish a command, the last one will be aborted as if `<Esc>` or `<C-C>` was typed."

Comment: FWIW, I find `33GI`/`33GA`/etc., without `:normal`, perfectly fine and, frankly, as short and easy as can be. That's how I would do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By default you go to start of the line.
For example, 5gg will take you to 0th character position on 5th line.

You can combine multiple commands with the help of pipe (|) character.
You cannot combine the navigation commands since the moment you type your first navigation command it executes moving the cursor. When you type in next command such as A (Append at the end of the line), it executes too.